# Running a Spring Boot Camel inside Jboss Fuse

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

I have a application running **Spring Boot Camel** which consume message from a ActiveMQ and write to a file:

```
@Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("activemq:queue:MyQueue").to("file:/tmp/somemessages/");
  }
```

Very simple and works fine if run `mvn spring-boot:run`.

But now i need generate a **bundle jar** to install in my RedHat Fuse OSGi container. Everything was installed and started without error, see:

[image]
So, my **camel-app** is **Active** but after produce some messages in my **ActiveMQ Queue** nothing works as i expect, so the file was not generated.

How can i see if something is wrong ? Application Console Log or something like this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a good practice. Spring Boot is intended for running Standalone. In an OSGi based runtime such as Red Hat Fuse or Apache Karaf/ServiceMix you should deploy OSGi apps, which with Camel is camel-blueprint (you can also use Java routes with blueprint). So take a look at examples how to do that, and there should be examples shipped with Red Hat Fuse you can look at.

Comment: No Fuse has 5 runtimes: Fuse Standalone (eg just Java Main), Fuse Karaf, Fuse EAP, and Fuse on OpenShift (eg Spring Boot), and recently also Fuse Online. As you are using Fuse Karaf, then we only support Karaf with OSGi Blueprint.

Comment: I created a project using BluePrint and now works. So is it mandatory the use of BluePrint with Fuse Karak ? How can i use only plain Java Class (Router) ?

Comment: In the blueprint XML you can add references to java classes, or packages where they are and Camel will use those. Should work similar as if you are using a Spring XML file. See using Java at: https://camel.apache.org/spring.html

Comment: Thanks @Claus I will try

Answer (score 1):

> How can i see if something is wrong ? Application Console Log or something like this ?

The simple answer is you can run diagnostic command on your bundle by running following command inside your shell console:

```
bundle:diag {your-bundle-id}
```

You may replace `{your-bundle-id}` by preferred bundle id that is 231 in the picture. There is also [a complete list of Apache Karaf commands](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_available_commands) that may be useful for further requirements.

Comment: in the case of errors bundle:diag is the most simple way to find out what's going wrong within your bundle (missing dependencies and so on), but generally as @claus-ibsen said the best way of implementing camel routes in an OSGi environment is using camel blueprint.